# For All Unique Combinations of 60 A's and 20 B's Number of Combinations that have BB

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

Here is my question. I have 60 A's and 20 B's and need to find out the number of unique combinations of those where B shows up consecutively at least once.

For example (6 A's and 2 B's):

AAAAAABB = 1

AAAAABAB = 0

AAAABBAA = 1

Comment: Find the number of ways to arrange the things so that _no_ two $B$s are adjacent, and subtract that number from the number of all ways to arrange the items without restriction.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. Any advice on how to figure this out? Maybe with a very simple example?

Comment: Exactly what André Nicolas answered. Say you have 3 $A$s and 2 $B$s. Setting up the $A$s gives you $1,A,2,A,3,A,4$ - four possible places in which you can place _one_ of the $B$s (or none). You have two $B$s, so you can place them in holes $(1,2),\, (1,3),\, (1,4),\,(2,3),\,(2,4),\,(3,4)$, altogether $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ possibilities.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a link to somewhere that I could read up more on this subject? Also, possibly explain the notation of (4 2)

Comment: The notation is standard notation for _binomial coefficients_. Read up on them, they're very useful, you can't get much done in combinatorics without them.

Comment: Ok. That is coming back to me now. Thanks. With your solution, can't I also place them in (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), or (4,4)? I am really looking for the times that they would be consecutive.

Comment: No, that's the point, the number of ways to have two $B$s together at least once is the total number of ways to arrange the $N_A + N_B$ objects, minus the number of ways to arrange them so that no two $B$s are adjacent. $\binom{N_A + N_B}{N_B} - \binom{N_A+1}{N_B}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's count the ways that $B$ **doesn't** occur  $2$ or more times in a row.

Line up the $A$'s. They determine $61$ "gaps" (I am counting in the endgaps).

We can **choose**  $20$ of these gaps to put a $B$ into in $\dbinom{61}{20}$ ways.

Subtract this from the total number of words, which is $\dbinom{80}{20}$.

**Added:** We want to count the number of **good** words, where a word is good if it has (somewhere or other) two or more consecutive $B$'s. It is much easier to count the total number of words, which is $\binom{80}{20}$, and subtract the number of **bad** words, words that nowhere have $2$ or more $B$'s in a row. So we concentrate on counting the bad words. For the sake of illustration, I will assume that there are $12$ $A$'s and $5$ $B$'s. This is because I will be drawing a sort of picture, and don't want to type $60$ $A$'s.

How do we make a bad word, that is, a word of length $17$, with $12$ $A$'s and $5$ $B$'s, and imagine lining up the $12$ $A$'s like this.
$$ A \quad A \quad A \quad A \quad A \quad A \quad A \quad A \quad A \quad A \quad A \quad A 
$$
Where can the $5$ $B$'s go? No two $B$'s can be next to each other, so any $B$ must be placed either in a gap between $2$ consecutive $A$'s or at the left end or at the right end. There are $11$ gaps between consecutive $A$'s, and two end places, which I called endgaps. So there are $11+2=13$ places where the $B$'s can go. To make a bad word, we must **choose** $5$ of these $13$ places to put a $B$ into. This choosing can be done in $\binom{13}{5}$ ways.

Comment: I am sure that what you are saying is correct. However, I am still new to this level of math/statistics. Could you break it down a little more in layman's terms?

Comment: I will try, probably not immediately. Need to know whether you understand binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{r}$, sometimes called ${}_nC_r$ or $C(n,r)$ or something related in high school. If you do, you presumably understand the $\binom{80}{20}$ part. Anyway, I really do need some indication of the state of your knowledge. Once I have that, will add to the post, and leave it there temporarily at least.

Comment: I took calculus in high school and college, but it has been a few years. The binomial coefficients look familiar, but I will have to read up on them as a refresher.

Comment: After some quick reading, I remember the binomial coefficients. Do you think you could explain the endgaps? I am just wondering exactly how they work, especially because you can place more than one B into each of the gaps.

Comment: The binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{r}$ gives us the number of ways to **choose** $r$ objects from $n$ distinct objects. For example the number of poker hands is $\binom{52}{5}$. We have $\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$, though that is not the quickest way to compute it. If you do not know these things, it becomes very difficult to explain matters in less than a few pages. They are absolutely necessary for problems of the type you raised.

Comment: What you are saying makes complete sense. I think I now better understand your solution. You basically are only putting single B's into each of the gaps. That is all of the possibilities where we will not have BB in any of the gaps. Then you go back to calculate all of the total combinations for B by using (60+20 20) and then subtracting the ways that we don't have BB. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Perhaps what I just added to the post is now superfluous, but I will leave it, at least for a while.

Comment: I think what you added is great. Especially for other people who are new to this or need a refresher (me).